# ER_PARSE_ERROR when using NodeJS to insert multiple values in a mySQL table

Tags: mysql, node.js, parsing, insert

I'm using NodeJS to insert my data in a table. I keep getting this weird error.

The code looks like this:

```
fs.watch('./Assetto1/results/', (eventType, filename) => {
 console.log("EventType:"+eventType);
 if (eventType == "rename") {
    //Gets most recent .json file loads it using require
    console.log("Debug: Rename");
    console.log("./Assetto1/results/"+filename);
    Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 1000);
    result = require("./Assetto1/results/"+filename);
    console.log(result.TrackName);

    //extracts the data out of the file and puts it in mySQL table
    connection.query('INSERT INTO results(1GUID, 1NAME, 1NATION, 1CARMODEL, 
        1CARSKIN, 1BESTTIME, 1TOTALTIME) VALUES (' + 
        race.getResultDriverGuid(result, 0) 
        + ',' + race.getResultDriverName(result, 0) + ',' + 
        race.getResultDriverNation(result, 0) + ',' + 
        race.getResultDriverCarModel(result, 0) + ',' + 
        race.getResultDriverCarSkin(result, 0) + ',' + 
        race.getResultDriverBestLap(result, 0) + ',' + 
        race.getResultDriverTotalTime(result, 0) + ');');

 }
})
```

The error looks something like that:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th                                                                                                                                                             at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '!,                                                                                                                                                             -,mercedes_sls_gt3,Black_Falcon_Dubai_24H_2,159303,688052)' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequ                                                                                                                                                             ences/Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.                                                                                                                                                             js:77:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                                                                                                                                                             278:23)
at Parser.write (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:                                                                                                                                                             48)
at Connection.query (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
at FSWatcher.fs.watch (/home/main.js:49:14)
at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:182:13)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:130:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.                                                                                                                                                             
js:425:8)
at Protocol.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Protocol._delegateError (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.j                                                                                                                                                             
s:390:10)
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:                                                                                                                                                             
12)
at Query.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Query.Sequence.end (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Seque                                                                                                                                                             
nce.js:78:12)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.                                                                                                                                                             
js:90:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                                                                                                                                                             
278:23)
at Parser.write (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
```

It looks like it's getting the right information out of the json - and obviously, that's not the problem. But it won't insert it into my table. I really dont understand what's wrong. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: check if the results of `race.getResult*` are all strings else convert them to string with `race.getResultDriverGuid(result, 0).toString()`.

Comment: isn't that kinda unnecessary? I'm using varchars in my table.

Comment: will any of them return error or nil ?

Comment: It doesn't even get inserted into the table. It throws the error before.

Comment: Try printing them before the `connection.query()` using `console.log(race.getResultDriverGuid(result, 0));`.. just an example.

Comment: @Arihant works without a problem